# Benchmark on one machine too extreme

Tags: benchmarking

I run a basic benchmark on my machines:

```
time echo "scale=3000;4*a(1)" | bc -l
```

This computes Pi to 3000 decimal places. The general expected time in my experience is 35-60 seconds on a Raspberry Pi B+, 2, 3.

One of my machines is giving 24 seconds, which is far out of the ordinary. This machine is a Raspberry Pi 3. My other Pi 3s give a consistent 48 seconds.  I have checked the governor (it is ondemand), boot config parameters and rebooted to make sure its clean.

I am **not** asking for alternative benchmark systems. I do know what I have is shakey (does not test multiple CPUs etc...), but the differences are surprising and consistent.

What could be causing such anomolous behavior?

UPDATE: I have started looking at the problem again. I used a fresh install of the OS and added extra programs one by one. It seems the slowdown happens when using the packages `openmpi-bin` and `python-mpi4py`. I am investigating further.

Comment: Does it still happen if you swap SD cards?

Comment: @joan : will test as soon as I have physical access.

Comment: My RPi 2 B ran this in `38.5` seconds. I think the bigger problem is that your testing methodology is unsound.

Comment: install `htop` and run it during your test. It will show all processes and the load on each core.

Answer (score 4):

Running that command to bench your RPi is not so acurate. That command will burn 1/4 cores of your Pi, thats why you get weirds results. Try to activate all 4 cores at 100%.

I coded a small benchmark script for raspberry (**multi-core benchmark**), to test it just copy and paste this command on your RPi:

```
curl https://raw.githubusercontent.com/aikoncwd/rpi-benchmark/master/rpi-benchmark.sh | sudo bash
```

It will test your **CPU, Memory** and **microSD-IO**. Here is my result for my overclocked RPi3:

```
Raspberry Pi Benchmark Test
Author: AikonCWD

temp=39.2'C
arm_freq=1400
core_freq=550
sdram_freq=575
microsd_clock=91.667 MHz

Running CPU test...
    total time:                          15.0670s
    temp=54.8'C

Running MEMORY test...
    total time:                          2.1438s
    temp=55.8'C

Running THREADS test...
    total time:                          7.6511s
    temp=58.0'C

Running HDPARM test...
    Timing buffered disk reads: 114 MB in  3.04 seconds =  37.47 MB/sec
    temp=49.4'C

Running DD WRITE test...
    536870912 bytes (537 MB) copied, 15.2853 s, 35.1 MB/s
    temp=46.2'C

Running DD READ test...
    536870912 bytes (537 MB) copied, 14.2355 s, 37.7 MB/s
    temp=45.1'C


AikonCWD's rpi-benchmark completed!
```

Try to run this benchmark over all your RPies and compare/share results here.

Feel free to fork my script and edit the values for a more "hardcore" benchmark :)

Comment: I do understand the limits of my approach. I just find the results surprising, so I thought there was something I overlooked.

Answer (score 2):

For what it's worth, I just ran that same test on a stock Raspberry Pi 3B running Raspbian Jessie and it completed in 24.3 seconds. It took 73.4 s on a Model B rev 2 running Wheezy.

Unless you have an idea of the system load beforehand, this isn't a particularly good general benchmark. Arbitrary-precision decimal number handling is a slightly special case. Maybe take a look at [Roy Longbottom's Raspberry Pi & Raspberry Pi 2 Benchmarks](http://www.roylongbottom.org.uk/Raspberry%20Pi%20Benchmarks.htm) for some options.

Comment: Sorry, had some escape characters for what I was doing. Fixed now.

Comment: That is closed to what I have with my other machines, except for the one weird one.

Comment: My Pi 3b ran this in 24 seconds as well.  I think the question, @JohnSmith, is why does your other 3 not do it in 24s?